# Coq item 1.2.10 Type cast

Tags: coq

Not sure what the following means in the Coq manual v8.7.0 [item 1.2.10](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.7.0/refman/gallina.html#typecast):

- The expression “*term* : *type*” is a type cast expression. It enforces the type of *term* to be *type*.
- “*term* <: *type*” locally sets up the virtual machine for checking that *term* has type *type*.

My understanding is that the type check of the first one is done by Coq (some default), whereas the second one is done by a chosen Coq's VM (which might have different typing rules).

I try with the following example, and couldn't see any difference from their error message

```
Check (3 : bool). (* Error: The term "3" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "bool".*)
Check (3 <: bool). (* same as above*)
```

My question is that: might be this is the case where the default and VM behaves the same?

Moreover, it would be nice to have an example where the ":" and "<:" behaves differently, so people could be more careful of choosing one from the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the default reduction machinery and the VM reduction machinery are designed to enforce the same typing rules.

But they don't behave the same in the sense that, for some computations, the verification time may be of a different order of magnitude.

Here is an example

```
Time Check (refl_equal 1 : (10 ^ 200 - 9 * 10 ^ 199) / 10 ^ 199 = 1).
...
Finished transaction in 0.103  secs ...

Time Check (refl_equal 1 <: (10 ^ 200 - 9 * 10 ^ 199) / 10 ^ 199 = 1).
...
Finished transaction in 0.053 secs
```

This matters because large computations can occur in the middle of proofs.